# how to make a spring boot project child module of a parent

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I would like to create two modules (dao and api) under this parent project. Module api would be restful api using Spring Boot. Since spring boot projects all have spring-boot-starter-parent as the parent module, how do I make it a child module under another parent? My understanding is Java projects can only have one parent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `DependencyManagement` instead of parent

Not everyone likes inheriting from the spring-boot-starter-parent POM. You may have your own corporate standard parent that you need to use, or you may just prefer to explicitly declare all your Maven configuration

```
<dependencyManagement>
     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Source: [Spring Boot Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html)

Comment: does that mean I can't run "mvn spring-boot:run" in command line?

Comment: you can configure the plugin in your pom.xml like described here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/usage.html